# How to get the multiple images selected by the user in a form and display it in next page?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

`

```
  <?php
     ob_start();
     session_start();
     include_once 'dbconnect.php';
     $error = false;
     if ( isset($_POST['cust-submit2']) ) {
     $pass1 = trim($_POST['cust-acc-pwd']); 
     $pass1 = strip_tags($_POST['cust-acc-pwd']);
     $pass1 = htmlspecialchars($_POST['cust-acc-pwd']);
     $pass2 = trim($_POST['cust-confirm-pwd']);
     $pass2 = strip_tags($_POST['cust-confirm-pwd']);
     $pass2 = htmlspecialchars($_POST['cust-confirm-pwd']);
     $_POST = $_SESSION;
     $acc_no = $_POST['cust-acc-no'];

     echo "<h1>$acc_no</h1>";

     if(empty($pass1) || empty($pass2)){
       $error = true;
       $passError = "Please enter your password.";
       echo $passError;
     }else if( strlen($pass1) < 6) {
        $error = true;
        $passError = "Password must have atleast 6 characters.";
        echo $passError;
     }

     if (!$error){
        if($pass1 == $pass2){

            // password encrypt using SHA256();
            $newpass = hash('sha256', $pass1);


            $query = "UPDATE users SET userPass = '$newpass' WHERE 
         Account_no='$acc_no'";
            $res = mysql_query($query);


            if($res){
                $errTyp = "<h1>success</h1>";
                $errMSG = "<h2>Successfully Password Changed</h2>";
                echo $errTyp;
                echo $errMSG;
                unset($pass1);
                unset($pass2);
             } 
             else{
                $errMSG = "<h1>Failure!Try again later..</h1>";
                echo $errMSG;
            }
          }
           else{
            echo "Passwords do not match";
          }
        }
       if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
        // Counting number of checked checkboxes.
    $checked_count = count($_POST['check_list']);
     echo "You have selected following ".$checked_count." option(s): <br/>";
    // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
     foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $selected) {
      echo "<p>".$selected ."</p>";
       }
       }
        else{
       echo "<b>Please Select Atleast One Option.</b>";
      }
         }

         $_POST = $_SESSION;

       ?>
      <html>
       <head>
        <title>Online Bank</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" 








   href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script 
     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
      </script>
        <script 
    src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
     </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="banking.css">
        <script src="banking.js"></script>
      </head>
       <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="float-left">Online Bank</h1>
            <h1 class="float-right">Online Bank</h1>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <hr>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href="#">Register</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>
            <br>
            <div class="col-md-12">
            <form method="post" action="">
             Welcome <?php if(!empty($_POST['cust-acc-no'])) echo $_POST['cust-
             acc-no'] ; ?>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <h3 class="text-center">Customer Panel</h3>
                    <br>
                    <!-- <form method="post" action="">
                               Welcome <?php if(!empty($_POST['cust-acc-no'])) 
       echo $_POST['cust-acc-no'] ; ?> -->
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="cust-acc-pwd">Enter your New 
       Password</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cust-acc-
       pwd" id="cust-acc-pwd">
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="cust-confirm-pwd">Confirm your New Password:
        </label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="cust-
        confirm-pwd" id="cust-confirm-pwd">
                      </div>
                      <label for="usr">Select your Security Image: </label>
                      <br><br>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-primary" 
         name="cust-submit2"><a class="a-btn">Submit</a></button>
                    <!-- </form> -->
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8 d3 mt0">
                    <h3 class="text-center pb20 mt0">Select Upto 4 Random 
        Images</h3>
                    <div class="d3-2">
                        <div class="d4">
                          <div class="d5">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="col-md-4"><img 
        src="reg_images/01.jpg" class="reg-img">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                      <label><input type="checkbox" 
        name="check_list[]" value="01.jpg"  id="img1"></label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4"><img 
       src="reg_images/02.jpg" class="reg-img">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                      <label><input type="checkbox" 
        name="check_list[]" value="02.jpg" id="img2"></label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4"><img 
      src="reg_images/03.jpg" class="reg-img">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                      <label><input type="checkbox" 
      name="check_list[]" value="03.jpg"  id="img3"></label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-12 mt10">
                                <div class="col-md-4"><img 
     src="reg_images/04.jpg" class="reg-img">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                      <label><input type="checkbox" 
      name="check_list[]" value="04.jpg"  id="img4"></label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4"><img 
      src="reg_images/05.jpg" class="reg-img">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                      <label><input type="checkbox" 
      name="check_list[]" value="05.jpg"  id="img5"></label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4"><img 
       src="reg_images/06.jpg" class="reg-img">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                      <label><input type="checkbox" 
       name="check_list[]" value="06.jpg" id="img6"></label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-12 mt10">
                                <div class="col-md-4"><img 
      src="reg_images/07.jpg" class="reg-img">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                      <label><input type="checkbox" 
        name="check_list[]" value="07.jpg"  id="img7"></label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4"><img 
        src="reg_images/08.jpg" class="reg-img">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                      <label><input type="checkbox" 
       name="check_list[]" value="08.jpg" id="img8"></label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4"><img 
       src="reg_images/09.jpg" class="reg-img">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                      <label><input type="checkbox" 
       name="check_list[]" value="09.jpg" id="img9"></label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-12 mt10">
                                <div class="col-md-4"><img 
       src="reg_images/10.jpg" class="reg-img">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                      <label><input type="checkbox" 
         name="check_list[]" value="10.jpg"  id="img10"></label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4"><img 
          src="reg_images/11.jpg" class="reg-img">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                      <label><input type="checkbox" 
          name="check_list[]" value="11.jpg"  id="img11"></label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4"><img 
          src="reg_images/12.jpg" class="reg-img">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                      <label><input type="checkbox" 
              name="check_list[]" value="12.jpg"  id="img12"></label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-12 mt10">
                                <div class="col-md-4"><img 
         src="reg_images/13.jpg" class="reg-img">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                      <label><input type="checkbox" 
            name="check_list[]" value="13.jpg" id="img13"></label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4"><img 
              src="reg_images/14.jpg" class="reg-img">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                      <label><input type="checkbox" 
             name="check_list[]" value="14.jpg"  id="img14"></label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4"><img 
             src="reg_images/15.jpg" class="reg-img">
                                    <div class="checkbox">
                                      <label><input type="checkbox" 
               name="check_list[]" value="15.jpg" id="img15"></label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>


        </div>

      </body>
         <html>
```

`I have created a register page(signup2.php) where user is asked to choose the 4 security images for him., along with other details.
Then when the user log-in, out of the 4 images chosen by him I want to display one of the images out of the 4 randomly along with some other random images and the user should only be able to login if he selects the right image.
Also it is must for the user to select the 4 images else he should not be able to register.
How can I do this? I am developing the website using PHP with MySql.
Any quick help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: have u tried anything ?

Comment: Post the code of what you have done so far. SO is not a "dev-for-hire" website.

Comment: @RiazLaskar..I have added my code.Kindly help me!

Comment: @DanPhilip..Kindly go through my code and help me out!!

Comment: @Riaz Laskar...I have added my code.Kindly assist me!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you can use a hidden textbox. On the 4 images you add a onclick event that will update the value of the hidden textbox. So when the form is submited the textbox will be sent with the form, just check that textbox and see if it has the value you expect.

The code below is a example you should add more to make the image marked in someway to make the user understand that it is marked to but i leave that part for you.

```
<div>
    <input id="securityImage" type="hidden" value="" />
    <img src="1.png" onlick="$("#securityImage").val("1");" />
    <img src="2.png" onlick="$("#securityImage").val("2");" />
    <img src="3.png" onlick="$("#securityImage").val("3");" />
    <img src="4.png" onlick="$("#securityImage").val("4");" />
</div>
```

Comment: Hello Sir, I have added my code.Could you please go through it and help me. Like in my form there are 15 images out of which i want the user to choose any 4. Then I would to store these images into the database and then when the user tries to login I want to show total 6 images to him.1 out of the four he had chosen at the time of registration and the remaining 5 from the large image set stored in the database.Also I want that every time the page refreshes different set of images should appear.An answer would be of great help to me!